# How to display data from JSON as flex row in div ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Here is my code. I want to display data from JSON file as flex-row in div. But what I got is column. I use tailwind to display it as flex-row. Here is the expected output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8uAp.jpg

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
    import PostData from "../data/data.json";

    class Sneaker extends Component {
      state = {};
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {PostData.map((postDetail) => {
              return (
                <div className="flex flex-row bg-gray-400 w-2/3 mx-auto mt-10">
                  <div className="text-center w-1/4 p-2 m-2 bg-white">
                    <img className="w-64 h-64" src={postDetail.image} alt="" />
                    <h1>{postDetail.name}</h1>
                    <h1 className="text-red-500">${postDetail.price}</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

export default Sneaker;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the postData loop inside the flex-row div as below

```
<div className="flex flex-row bg-gray-400 w-2/3 mx-auto mt-10">
 {PostData.map((postDetail) => {
              return (                
                  <div className="text-center w-1/4 p-2 m-2 bg-white">
                    <img className="w-64 h-64" src={postDetail.image} alt="" />
                    <h1>{postDetail.name}</h1>
                    <h1 className="text-red-500">${postDetail.price}</h1>
                  </div>

              );
            })}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want put 3 items in a flex row you can write code like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PostData from "../data/data.json";

const perRow = 3;
class Sneaker extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {PostData.map((ignoreIt, i) => {
          return i % perRow === 0 ? (
            <div
              className="flex flex-row bg-gray-400 w-2/3 mx-auto mt-10"
              key={i}
            >
              {PostData.slice(i, i + perRow).map((postDetail, j) => {
                return (
                  <div
                    className="text-center w-1/4 p-2 m-2 bg-white"
                    key={i + j}
                  >
                    <img className="w-64 h-64" src={postDetail.image} alt="" />
                    <h1>{postDetail.name}</h1>
                    <h1>{j}</h1>
                    <h1 className="text-red-500">${postDetail.price}</h1>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          ) : null;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sneaker;
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thanks